# removing records from activerecord results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

`product_keywords` is an array of strings.

`gifts` is the result of an ActiveRecord query

Basically, I want to remove certain results from `gifts` (see `if` clause). If `gifts` was a normal array, it'd be fairly easy, but I don't want to lose the ActiveRecord functionality.

```
gifts.each do | gift |
  if product_keywords.all? { |keyword| gift.product.name.downcase.include? keyword }
    # ?????
  end
end
```

ETA: I don't want to edit the database. I just want to remove certain records from the results object.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```rb
gifts.reject!{ |gift| !product_keywords.include?(gift.product.name.downcase) }
```

Comment: Won't that destroy the database record?

Comment: you said ```Basically, I want to remove any results from gifts where product name does not match all of the provided keywords.```
This remove the product if not match with product_keywords
If you want remove the gift, then change
```ruby
gift.destroy unless product_keywords.include?(gift.product.name.downcase)
```

Comment: I explicitly said I wanted to restrict the *results*, not delete anything from the database.

Comment: please, review now

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what I was looking for.

`gifts = gifts.reject { | gift | !product_keywords.all? { |keyword| gift.product.name.downcase.include? keyword } }`